# extract only one part from xpath scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract from a web page information with xpath, but I'm getting the wrong information. In this code below I want to get `100` :

```
<div class="pricing">
 <p class="pricePerUnit">
  <p class="pricePerMeasure">
  £0.64
  <abbr title="per">/</abbr>
  100
```

I want to only get `100`, I tried this but it returns `£0.64 100`.  But,  I just want to retrieve the `100` :

```
`prices_mesure3 = `response.xpath('//p[@class="pricePerMeasure"]/text()').extract()`
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Can you add the closing tags to the HTML, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath support node indexing, so you can just add `[last()]` or `[2]` to your xpath:

```
In: response.xpath('//p[@class="pricePerMeasure"]/text()[last()]').extract_first()
Out: u'\n  100 '
```

Comment: Can you help me for another issue @Granitosaurus  please ?!

Comment: @uzumaki_naruto sure, what's the other issue?

Comment: this is the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075060/scrape-all-pages-from-one-url-in-start-urls-with-scrapy/43075225#43075225

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `XPath` expression to get `"100"` only

```
//p[@class="pricePerMeasure"]/text()[last()]
```

P.S. I suppose there are only 2 text nodes (`"£0.64"` and `"100"`) and you just missed closing tags...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just split the result and then take the last element?

```
prices_mesure3 = response.xpath('//p[@class="pricePerMeasure"]/text()').extract()[0].split()[-1]
```